# why i can not able to get the wifi info in flutter application running in background using flutter_background_service and network_info_plus plugin

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, wifi

I have added two dependencies which can get WIFI name and can run the application in background. The application is running perfectly in the background but it get null in background. And when the application is open then it can get WIFI name.

```
import 'package:awesome_notifications/awesome_notifications.dart';
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:network_info_plus/network_info_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter_background_service/flutter_background_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart ';

Future<void> initializeService() async {
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(const InitializationSettings(
      android: AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_launcher')));

  var service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
        const InitializationSettings(iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings()));
  }

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    final androidInfo = await deviceInfo.getWifiName();
    log("androidInfo======================>$androidInfo");
  }

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

  await service.configure(
      iosConfiguration:
          IosConfiguration(onBackground: iosBackground, onForeground: onStart),
      androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
          onStart: onStart,
          autoStart: true,
          notificationChannelId: "Foreground Service",
          isForegroundMode: true,
          initialNotificationTitle: "Foreground Service Running0..",
          foregroundServiceNotificationId: 90));
  service.startService();
}

@pragma("vm:entry-point")
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) {
  service.on("setAsForeground").listen((event) {
    log("Foreground=======================>");
  });

  service.on("setAsBackground").listen((event) {
    log("Background=======================>");
  });

  service.on("stopService").listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
  });

  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 4), (timer) async {
    final info = NetworkInfo();

    // var storedWIFI = '"AndroidWifi"';
    String storedWIFI = '"JioFiber_5G"';

    Connectivity()
        .onConnectivityChanged
        .listen((ConnectivityResult result) async {
      log("onConnectivityChanged===00001==============>$result");

      if (result == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
        var wifiName = await info.getWifiName();

        log("wifiName=====B4 condition===========$storedWIFI=========>$wifiName");

        if (storedWIFI == wifiName) {
          AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
            content: NotificationContent(
              id: 10,
              channelKey: 'general_notification',
              title: 'You are connected to $wifiName',
              body: 'You have checked in.',
              notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigText,
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    });

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        90,
        "Cool Service",
        "Awesom ${DateTime.now()}",
        const NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                "Foreground Service", "Foreground Service Running0..",
                ongoing: true)));
  });
}
```

**Got the solution finally
just need to add following permission in AndroidManifest.xml file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: would you like to try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939416/is-it-possible-to-get-the-wifi-ssid-in-the-background-service